# Why AVAudioPlayer has no sound?

Tags: swiftui

I got one button which can play and pause the audio, but I found the following code has no sound. Do you know why? If I put the AVAudioPlayer create code snippet in a dependent function `playAudio()`, it can play the sound but I cannot pause and continue playing.

## Reproducible code

```
import SwiftUI
import AVFoundation


struct ContentView: View {
    var shortname: String
    var id: Int
    @State var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer?
    
    
    init(shortname: String="rs", id: Int=1) {
        self.shortname = shortname
        self.id = id
        
        let fileName = self.shortname.lowercased() + "-" + String(id)
        guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: fileName, ofType: "mp3") else {
            print("[shark]", fileName + "is not found")
            return
        }
        do {
            audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: path))
            audioPlayer?.play()
        } catch {
            print("[shark], audioPlayer cannot load", path, error)
        }
        
    }
    

    var body: some View {
        
        Text("good")
            .onAppear {
                audioPlayer?.play()
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SwiftUI is picky about what you can do in an initializer for a View struct like this. A more reliable option is to move the loading into an ObservableObject:

```
class AudioManager : ObservableObject {
    var audioPlayer : AVAudioPlayer?
    
    func loadAudio(filename: String) {
        guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: filename, ofType: "mp3") else {
            print("[shark]", filename + "is not found")
            return
        }
        do {
            audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: path))
        } catch {
            print("[shark], audioPlayer cannot load", path, error)
        }
    }
    
    func playAudio() {
        audioPlayer?.play()
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var shortname: String = ""
    var id: Int = 0
    @ObservedObject var audioManager = AudioManager()
    

    var body: some View {
        
        Text("good")
            .onAppear {
                let fileName = self.shortname.lowercased() + "-" + String(id)
                audioManager.loadAudio(filename: fileName)
                audioManager.playAudio()
            }
    }
}
```

This plays for me on Xcode 12.3 and iOS 14

Comment: why you used **var audioPlayer : AVAudioPlayer?** couldn't we just use **var audioPlayer : AVAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()** when we use optional it makes us extra unwrapping. with my code, if even there is no file to play we would not get in trouble. because we are using do-catch in load or play. I know it was from OP, but I like to know the deference

Comment: Because it seems idiomatically correct here and quite Swift-like. We don't *know* that the AVAudioPlayer will be successfully loaded. It doesn't make sense to have a non-functional player there just to avoid an optional unwrap. Having the value be `nil` would make more sense in the event there was trouble initializing it. Plus, if you look at the headers for the empty initializer of AVAudioPlayer, it says it's meant to be used by subclasses -- the intent isn't just to use it to create blank players.

Comment: yes, but i did not meant about to create blank players, all purpose of  AVAudioPlayer is playing, isn`t that? So if you agree with me that all purpose of it is playing and we do use always and always do-catch is there and room left for using optional? I mean we can use with your explaining, but it put extra work for use for unwrapping.

Comment: It can't be initialized before `loadAudio`, because the filename isn't known. Therefore, it has to be optional until then unless a blank player is created. I've expressed why I think this is an idiomatically-correct decision. I also do not consider optional unwrapping extra work -- on the contrary, I consider it an important part of the type safety and nil checking system.